# Coloring text between pauses in beamer

Tags: beamer, color, pause

I use a lot of pauses. I would like to set something globally so that the most recent slide highlights (by bolding, making red, etc) the text that just appears. These lectures have many slides to them and I really don't want to have to use the alert command over and over.
For example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
This is a test. \pause
This is another test \pause
This is a third test.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I would like for the first slide to have only the first sentence appearing, in red.
The second slide would have the first sentence in black and the second sentence in red.
The third slide would have the first and second sentence in black and the third in red.

Again, I know this can be done using the alert commands, but upon the last 'grep' of my most recent slides, I have 138 pauses. I was hoping for a silver bullet. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

M

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. Please complete your code to make it compilable. This will make it much easier for people to help you and likely improve the quality and quantity of responses.

Comment: If you use `itemize` rather than just `\pause` you can say `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+-| alert@+>}` in your preamble to get this effect.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I often have prose on my slides and do not want to make a list with itemize or any other bulleted environment. I tried this bit of code and found it did work on slide which do have bulleted lists, but not on those using just pauses mid-paragraph.

Comment: After a few hours of tinkering, I have something. I defined a new command:

`\newcommand{\redpause}{\addtocounter{beamerpauses}{-1}\pause\color<+>{red}}`

If I use this instead of `\pause`, I seem to have the desired effect. However, I'm not sure how to adapt this if I want the newest viewable text to be bolded or have some other change in formatting.

Answer (score 6):

After a few hours of tinkering, I found an amicable solution. One can define a new command which sets incorporates a pause, sets back the counter, and makes the color red:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\redpause}{\addtocounter{beamerpauses}{-1}\pause\color<+>{red}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\redpause
This is a test. \redpause
This is another test. \redpause
This is a third test.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This works for changing the color, but I believe it would need to be tweaked to incorporate bold-facing text or some other method.